# What is meant by the continuity of the Hessian matrix

Tags: multivariable-calculus, continuity

I have a simple and short question: "What is meant by the continuity of the Hessian matrix?"

I guess it means that all the second partial derivatives of a function $f$ are continuous functions? is that the meaning? =)

Thank you for any help! =)

Comment: Both conditions are equivalent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right. By *continuity of the Hessian* of a function $f \colon U \subseteq \def\R{\mathbb R}\R^n \to \R^n$ the following is meant:

> The function $D^2f \colon U \to {\rm Mat}(n, \R)$, $x \mapsto \bigl(\partial_i\partial_j f(x)\bigr)_{ij}$, i. e. the Hessian of $f$, is continuous.

or the equivalent

> All second partial derivatives $\partial_i\partial_j f\colon U \to \mathbb R$, $1 \le i,j \le n$ of $f$ are contiuous.